# Is there a way in Google Apps Script to list the files located in several folders of my Google Drive in one same Google Sheets tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For some time now I have been working with the following script to list in one tab of a Spreadsheet the files contained in one folder of my Google Drive :

```
function List_Thumbnails() {
/* Adapted from Code written by @hubgit https://gist.github.com/hubgit/3755293
Updated since DocsList is deprecated  https://ctrlq.org/code/19854-list-files-in-google-drive-folder
*/


  // List all files and sub-folders in a single folder on Google Drive
  // declare the folder name
  var foldername = 'Thumbnails 1';

  // declare this sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Thumbs Import');
  // clear any existing contents
  sheet.clear();
  // append a header row
  sheet.appendRow(["Folder","Name", "Date Last Updated", "Size", "URL", "ID", "Description", "Type", "Download", "Date Created"]);


  // getFoldersByName = Gets a collection of all folders in the user's Drive that have the given name.
  // folders is a "Folder Iterator" but there is only one unique folder name called, so it has only one value (next)
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var foldersnext = folders.next();
  // Logger.log("THE FOLDER IS "+foldersnext);// DEBUG

  // declare an array to push data into the spreadsheet
  var data = [];

  // list files in this folder
  // myfiles is a File Iterator
  var myfiles = foldersnext.getFiles();

  // Logger.log("FILES IN THIS FOLDER"); DEBUG

  // loop through files in this folder
  while (myfiles.hasNext()) {
    var myfile = myfiles.next();
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var fdate = myfile.getLastUpdated(); 
    var fsize = myfile.getSize();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    var fid = myfile.getId();
    var fdesc = myfile.getDescription();
    var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();
    var fdown = myfile.getDownloadUrl();
    var fcreate = myfile.getDateCreated()
    
    //Logger.log("File Name is "+myfile.getName()); //Logger.log("Date is "+myfile.getLastUpdated()); //Logger.log("Size is "+myfile.getSize());
    //Logger.log("URL is "+myfile.getUrl()); //Logger.log("ID is "+myfile.getId()); //Logger.log("Description is "+myfile.getDescription());
    //Logger.log("File Type is "+myfile.getMimeType());

    // Populate the array for this file
    data = [ 
      foldersnext,
      fname,
      fdate,
      fsize,
      furl,
      fid,
      fdesc,
      ftype,
      fdown,
      fcreate
    ];
    //Logger.log("data = "+data); //DEBUG
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  } // Completes listing of the files in the named folder

  // Now get the subfolder
  // subfolders is a Folder Iterator
  var subfolders = foldersnext.getFolders();
  //Logger.log("THE SUBFOLDER(S) ARE"); DEBUG HEADING

  // now start a loop on the SubFolder list
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolderdata = [];
    var mysubfolders = subfolders.next();
    var mysubfolder = mysubfolders.getName();  
    //Logger.log("Subfolder name:"+mysubfolder); //DEBUG

    // Get the files
    // mysubfiles is a File Iterator
    var mysubfiles = mysubfolders.getFiles();
    //Logger.log("FILES IN THIS FOLDER"); //DEBUG HEADING

    // now start a loop on the files in the subfolder
    while (mysubfiles.hasNext()) {
      var smyfile = mysubfiles.next();
      var sfname =  smyfile.getName();
      var sfdate =  smyfile.getLastUpdated(); 
      var sfsize =  smyfile.getSize();
      var sfurl =  smyfile.getUrl();
      var sfid =  smyfile.getId();
      var sfdesc =  smyfile.getDescription();
      var sftype =  smyfile.getMimeType();
      var sfdown = myfile.getDownloadUrl();
      var sfcreate = myfile.getDateCreated()
      
      //Logger.log("Subfolder is "+foldersnext+"/"+mysubfolder); 
      //Logger.log("File Name is "+ smyfile.getName()); Logger.log("Date is "+ smyfile.getLastUpdated()); Logger.log("Size is "+ smyfile.getSize());
      //Logger.log("URL is "+ smyfile.getUrl()); Logger.log("ID is "+ smyfile.getId()); Logger.log("Description is "+ smyfile.getDescription());Logger.log("File Type is "+ smyfile.getMimeType());
      subfolderdata = [ 
        (foldersnext+"/"+mysubfolder),
        sfname,
        sfdate,
        sfsize,
        sfurl,
        sfid,
        sfdesc,
        sftype,
        sfdown,
        sfcreate
      ];
      //Logger.log("subfolderdata = "+subfolderdata);
      sheet.appendRow(subfolderdata);
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to achieve now, if it's possible and with a similar script, is to list the contents of several folders oh my Drive at once. The folders could be called "Thumbnails 1", "Thumbnails 2", "Thumbnails 3", "Thumbnails 4" and "Thumbnails 5". Each one below the previous one and sharing the header
Also, I would like to know whether this script could be executed using a trigger after each submission of a form whose responses are linked to the same spreadsheet where this script will be run. Each time this form gets submitted, the contents of the folders to be listed may change since the file uploads of the form point directly to these folders.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script requires only minor changes to meet your goal.

- Instead of naming a single folder and then listing the files in the folder and ALL sub-folders, this answer lists specific folders and ignores sub-folders.
- The script can be triggered by an Installable `onFormSubmit`

---

Delete:
`var foldername = 'Thumbnails 1';`

Substitute:
`var folderNames = ['Thumbnails 1','Thumbnails 2','Thumbnails 3','Thumbnails 4','Thumbnails 5']`

---

Delete:
`var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);`

Substitute:
`for (var i=0;i<folderNames.length;i++){`
`var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderNames[i]);`

---

Delete:

- from: `// Now get the subfolder`
- to: `}` (line 115)
  Note: the closing brace on line 116 remains and closes the `for` loop begun in the previous edit.

---

**Script**

```
function List_ThumbnailsOnly() {
/* Adapted from Code written by @hubgit https://gist.github.com/hubgit/3755293
Updated since DocsList is deprecated  https://ctrlq.org/code/19854-list-files-in-google-drive-folder
*/


  // List all files in a single folder on Google Drive
  // declare an array of folders
  var folderNames = ['Thumbnails 1','Thumbnails 2','Thumbnails 3','Thumbnails 4','Thumbnails 5']

  // declare this sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Thumbs Import');
  // clear any existing contents
  sheet.clear();
  // append a header row
  sheet.appendRow(["Folder","Name", "Date Last Updated", "Size", "URL", "ID", "Description", "Type", "Download", "Date Created"]);


  // getFoldersByName = Gets a collection of all folders in the user's Drive that have the given name.
  // folders is a "Folder Iterator" but there is only one unique folder name called, so it has only one value (next)

  for (var i=0;i<folderNames.length;i++){

    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderNames[i]);
    var foldersnext = folders.next();
    // Logger.log("THE FOLDER IS "+foldersnext);// DEBUG

    // declare an array to push data into the spreadsheet
    var data = [];

    // list files in this folder
    // myfiles is a File Iterator
    var myfiles = foldersnext.getFiles();

    // Logger.log("FILES IN THIS FOLDER"); DEBUG

    // loop through files in this folder
    while (myfiles.hasNext()) {
      var myfile = myfiles.next();
      var fname = myfile.getName();
      var fdate = myfile.getLastUpdated(); 
      var fsize = myfile.getSize();
      var furl = myfile.getUrl();
      var fid = myfile.getId();
      var fdesc = myfile.getDescription();
      var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();
      var fdown = myfile.getDownloadUrl();
      var fcreate = myfile.getDateCreated()
      
      //Logger.log("File Name is "+myfile.getName()); //Logger.log("Date is "+myfile.getLastUpdated()); //Logger.log("Size is "+myfile.getSize());
      //Logger.log("URL is "+myfile.getUrl()); //Logger.log("ID is "+myfile.getId()); //Logger.log("Description is "+myfile.getDescription());
      //Logger.log("File Type is "+myfile.getMimeType());

      // Populate the array for this file
      data = [ 
        foldersnext,
        fname,
        fdate,
        fsize,
        furl,
        fid,
        fdesc,
        ftype,
        fdown,
        fcreate
      ];
      //Logger.log("data = "+data); //DEBUG
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }// Completes listing of the files in the named folder
  } // Completes loop of Folder names
}
```

Comment: Thnk you It works with some minor correction var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername[i]);    is       var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderNames[i]);    . If you fix it, I give you the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Argh. Thanks for the correction.